How do I non-dimensionalise this model?
I have two predator-prey population models:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dN}{dt} &= rN \left(1 - \frac{N}{k}\right) - v(N)P \\
\frac{dP}{dt} &= cv(N)P - mP - qEP
\end{align*}
where v(N) is
\begin{align*}
v(N) = \frac{aN}{1 + ahN}
\end{align*}
$N$ is prey population size
$P$ is predator population size
$r$ is the intrinsic growth rate of prey
$k$ is the carrying capacity
$v(N)$ is the rate of prey consumption per predator
$a$ is the attack rate
$h$ is the handling time
$c$ is the conversion efficiency
$m$ is the predator mortality rate in absence of food
$E$ is fishing effort
$q$ is catchability coefficient
Can someone help explain non-dimensionalisation and how I would apply it to here? Apparently, I am somehow suppose to arrive at the following equations:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{d\tau} &= x\left(1 - \frac{x}{\gamma} - \frac{y}{1 + x}\right) \\
\frac{dy}{d\tau} &= \beta y \left(\frac{x}{1 + x} - \alpha\right)
\end{align*}

You nondimensionalize by introducing scale factors. Maybe start with $N = kx$ and $t = C\tau$ and see where that takes you. A bit more step-by-step guidance is here.

ah, yes that was my main focus. How do I know what scale factor do I use?

Just from pattern matching with the final equations, $x=ahN$, $y=P$, and $\tau$ chosen to make the leading coefficient of the first equation $1$ seems like it should work

$
\def\a{\alpha}  \def\b{\beta}  \def\g{\gamma}
\def\o{{\tt1}}  \def\t{\tau}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\CR#1{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\RLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\td#1{\frac{d#1}{d\t}}
$In the given equations, $\CR{\frac Nk,\,ahN}$ are summed with the number $\o$ and therefore must be dimensionless quantities.
Let's choose one of these as our first dimensionless variable
and see how far it gets us
$$\eqalign{
x &= ahN \qif N=\frac{x}{ah} \\
v &= \frac{aN}{\o+ahN} \;=\; \frac1h\fracLR{x}{\o+x} \\
\\
\dot N
 &= rN\LR{\o-\frac Nk} -vP \\
\frac{\dot x}{ah}
 &= \frac{rx}{ah}\LR{\o-\frac x{kah}} - \frac1h\fracLR{x}{\o+x}P \\
\dot x
 &= rx\LR{\o-\frac x{kah}} - \fracLR{x}{\o+x}aP \\
}$$
Introduce the notation $Y\sim Z$ to mean that quantities
are dimensionally equal, then note that in that
last equation $rx \sim aP.\;$
This gives us our second dimensionless variable
$$ y = \frac{aP}{r} \sim x $$
Let's see what this buys us (along with setting $\,\g=kah$)
$$\eqalign{
\dot x
 &= rx\LR{\o-\frac x{kah}} - \fracLR{x}{\o+x}ry \\
 &= rx\LR{\o-\frac x\g - \frac{y}{\o+x}} \\
}$$
We can use the rate $r$ to make time our third dimensionless variable
$$\eqalign{
\t &= rt \qiq
\td x &= x\LR{\o-\frac x\g - \frac{y}{\o+x}} \\
}$$
The first equation has been fully non-dimensionalized, now let's fix  the second equation
$$\eqalign{
\dot P &= \lR{c\red{v}-m-qE}\,P \\
\frac{r\dot y}a &= \LR{c\,\red{\frac{1}{h}\fracLR{x}{\o+x}}-m-qE}\frac{ry}{a} \\
\dot y &= \frac{c}{h}\LR{\frac{x}{\o+x}-\frac{hm+hqE}{c}}y \\
\td y &= \frac{c}{rh}\LR{\frac{x}{\o+x}-\frac{hm+hqE}{c}}y \\
}$$
Assigning Greek names to the various parameter groupings
produces the desired form
$$\eqalign{
\a &= \frac{hm+hqE}{c}, \qq \b = \frac{c}{rh} \\ 
\td y &= \b y\LR{\frac{x}{\o+x}-\a} \\\\
}$$

That was a long-winded explanation. There is a more systematic/algebraic approach to such problems which is described in the Wikipedia link in the first comment on your post.
